# Correct scale in print composer with QuickMapServices layer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, quickmapservices

I'm trying to prepare basemaps from the south of France based off Google Satellite imagery (QuickMapServices).

I'm exporting these basemaps using the Print Composer, with a scalebar and coordinate grid. Under default settings, the coordinate grid is fine and accurate but the scalebar (and the lengths from the measuring tool) is approximately 40% too long.

When I change the project to the equal-distance RGF92/EPSG:2154, the scales are now correct in the normal project viewer but completely wrong in the print composer and the coordinate grid is completely wrong (e.g. giving a coordinate of -1.084, 35.426 instead of 2.902 43.406).

What do I need to do to fix this?